# Does this have a name and does it work?

Tags: statistics, terminology

I am evaluating both the effectiveness of a program using a pre and post survey and the effectiveness of the survey. I have a variety of statistical methods I am using to evaluate this data, but one approach occurred to me. I have tried searching for the technique with no success.

The questions on my survey are right or wrong, so I can build a response matrix. For example {Pre Correct, Pre Incorrect} x {Post Correct, Post Incorrect}. I can fill the grid with the count of respondents who then fit each category (correct/correct, correct/incorrect, incorrect/correct, incorrect/incorrect). I can then measure net how many respondents "improved" by taking the difference of (incorrect/correct) and (correct/incorrect).

Effectively, I'm counting how many people who answered incorrectly on the pre and correctly on the post, then cancelling for anyone who went in the opposite direction. I can then convert this to a percent of the population and average over all questions for an aggregate measurement.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? I'm looking for Google-able words to be able to read about the efficacy of such a technique. And I preemptively apologize if this is a dumb question and/or posted in the wrong place. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the confusion matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix

Comment: @Adrian That actually helps a lot! It looks like the more general name for this technique (outside of machine learning) is a Contingency Table. I'll have to ruminate on how the Confusion Matrix computations apply to my situation. For example, accuracy is a measurement that I would want minimized.
I haven't found the measurement I'm interested in yet. Equivalently, it would be (FN-FP)/(TP+TN+FP+FN) for a Confusion Matrix.

Comment: Glad to be of help!